# Why no c# native compiler project on win32?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, winapi

Nowadays open source projects are almost everywhere, especially for compilers, c++ compilers, pascal compilers, even for d language, go language, but why there is not a c# compiler, which works on native windows? Is there any legal restrictions, or any technical barrier? or no market requirement?

I was wondering on this question for quite a long time.

edit:
I made another wrong assumption. I works mainly on win32 platform, so my question is for win32 platform (x86). Actually I know mono, and as far as I know, mono can't compile to native & AOT on win32.

Comment: I think you are making the wrong assumption that every FOSS project is hosted on sourceforge... Ever heard of savannah or self-hosted projects?

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific on win32/x86. How can I reopen this thread? I think now it's a valid question.

Comment: SO doesn't want to be a discussion board. So "Why not" questions are not popular. You can try again, but also change the focus, not just the details.

Comment: Microsoft's C# compiler *is* open-source: [The .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") provides open-source C# and Visual Basic compilers with rich code analysis APIs.](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) I don't know whether it includes a compiler backend as well. The [CoreRT](https://github.com/dotnet/corert), however, does provide the .NET native compiler toolchain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you seen the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Start)?

Comment: It's sad that only the monotouch is able to compile c# into native cpu code, which is not free, not for win32 neither.